# Asp.net MVC: Cannot select the right attribute value in my View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

My code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div class="container div1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 2)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position:relative; background-image: url(@Model[i].ImgLink); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" />
                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="" data-id=@Model[i].Id>Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count; i += 2)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid" />

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

</div>





<div class="container div2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position:relative; background-image: url(@Model[i].ImgLink); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" data-id="@Model[i].VideoId"/>
                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu" id="@Model[i].VideoId">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Video", new {id = Model[i].Id})">Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>

            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 1; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" data-id="@Model[i].VideoId"/>

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu" id="@Model[i].VideoId">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Video", new {id = Model[i].Id})">Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            @for (int i = 2; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
            {
                <div class="hov" style="position: relative; background-image: url( @Model[i].ImgLink ); background-position: center; background-size: cover; margin-top: 2%;">

                    <img src="@Model[i].ImgLink" class="img-fluid clickable" data-id="@Model[i].VideoId"/>

                    <img src="~/Videos/play_button.png" class="play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model[i].Id" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="@Model[i].Id">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <iframe width="560" class="venobox" height="315" src=@("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + Model[i].VideoId) frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu" id="@Model[i].VideoId">
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Video", new {id = Model[i].Id})">Delete</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Edit </a> </li>
                </ul>
            }

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="out-click"> something</div>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .play-btn {
        width: 3.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .img-fluid {
        width: 30em;
        height: auto;
    }

    .hov:hover .play-btn {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

        .row .column {
            flex: 33.3%;
            width: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0 4px;
            height: 100%;
        }

            .row .column .img-fluid {
                margin-top: 2%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

    .menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px 0px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 30px lightgrey;
        position: absolute;
        transform-origin: center;
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    }

        .menu.show {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
            transform-origin: top left;
        }

    .menu-item {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        transition: 0.1s;
        color: #666;
    }

        .menu-item:hover {
            background-color: #eee;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .out-click {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
    }

    @@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        .row .column {
            flex: 50%;
        }

        .play-btn {
            width: 3em;
        }

        .img-fluid {
        }
    }

    @@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .row .column {
            flex: 100%;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
</style>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var width = $(window).width();
            if (width <= 800 && width > 600) {
                $(".div2").remove();
            }
            else {
                $(".div1").remove();
            }

        });

        //const clickable = $(".clickable");
        const clickable = document.getElementsByClassName("clickable");
        for (var i = 0; i < clickable.length; i++) {
            console.log(clickable[i].getAttribute('src'));
        }


        //const menu = $(".menu");
        const menu_aux = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
        //const outClick = $(".out-click");
        const outClick = document.getElementsByClassName("out-click");

        for (var i = 0; i < clickable.length; i++) {
            clickable[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                //for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                var id = clickable[i].getAttribute('data-id');
                var menu = document.getElementById(id);
                    menu.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
                    menu.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
                menu.classList.add('show');
                console.log(id);
                //}
                for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) {
                    outClick[j].style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < outClick.length; i++) {
            outClick[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                for (var j = 0; j < menu_aux.length; j++) {
                    menu_aux[j].classList.remove('show');
                }
                for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) {
                    outClick[j].style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
}
```

In my event listener in the script, I select which menu to display on the screen by Id, the is is Unique vor each video, it is its videoId. The problem is that it always displays the same menu for the wrong video, so that when I select "Delete" from the menu, it deletes the wrong video (always the same video). The ids are unique. Also, I work in my div with the class div2 (div1 appears to the screen for screens with smaller widths). I checked my body (html) in the browser on right click and "inspect", the videoId I set as the id for the menu is unique for every video and clickable has the right data-id attribute, so I cannot understand why on console.log it displays the wrong videoId (from the data-id attribute of every element with "clickable" class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach had issues due to the scope of `id` inside your loop to add the event listeners. By getting the id before adding the listener and making it local to that loop iteration with `let` also fixes your issue. Both approaches are valid.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < clickable.length; i++) {
        let id = clickable[i].getAttribute('data-id');
        clickable[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            //for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
            var menu = document.getElementById(id);
                menu.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
                menu.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
            menu.classList.add('show');
            console.log(id);
            //}
            for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) {
                outClick[j].style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! In my event listener I was getting the id of clickable[i], but i has a constant value that never changes after all clickable[i] elements in my for get their event listeners. I just wrote e.target (event.target) instead of clickable[i] in my function handler, which gets called on every right click.

```
for (var i = 0; i < clickable.length; i++) {
            clickable[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                //for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                var target = e.target;
                var id = $(target).attr('data-id');
                console.log(id);
                var menu = document.getElementById(id);
                    menu.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
                    menu.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
                menu.classList.add('show');
                
                //}
                for (var j = 0; j < outClick.length; j++) {
                    outClick[j].style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
```